# Как перевести предложение с притяжательным падежом, которое состоит из терминов

Tags: перевод, выражения, английский

Есть такое предложение: `This is known as the agent's running execution context.`
Но проблема в том чтобы сохранить английские термины в их исходном состоянии. То есть из всего этого предложения нельзя переводить `agent` и `running execution context`.

И как можно передать в таком случае притяжательный падеж, чтобы читателю было понятно что к чему относится?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Притяжательность можно попытаться выразить описательно, а не падежно

> Он известен как `running execution context`, принадлежащий / относящийся к / связанный с / зависящий от / зависимый от / который исполняет / которым управляет `agent`

Comment: Мне нравится ваше решение!

Comment: @MaximPro а мне - ваше )))

Answer (score 1):

Если допустимо выделение полужирным шрифтом, я бы оформил это примерно так:

> Это известно как **running execution context** этого **agent**'a.

или

> Это известно как **agent's running execution context**.

Если можно использовать только кавычки, то:

> Это известно как "agent's running execution context".

Что касается притяжательного падежа как такового, то обычно он передается дополнительным местоимением и, при необходимости, окончанием: ("этого **agent**'a").

Comment: Неплохо, но врятли это будет легко восприниматься для любого читателя.

Comment: Такой вариант хорош, если необходимо в максимально возможной степени сохранить изначальный текст. Если допустимо использовать более свободную форму перевода, то можно воспользоваться вариантом, предложенным **Баян Купи-ка**.

Comment: Я когда сам пытался что-то придумать, то ваши варианты мне приходили в голову. Но они подходят в очень специфичных случаях. Человек, который будет впервые читать это, врятли сможет понять правильный посыл, особенно тот что с английским слабо знаком. А вот использовать дополнительные слова для связки двух рядом стоящих терминов, весьма удачная идея. Ведь по сути она не искажает текст, а лишь проясняет. В любом случае и вам спасибо что ответили на мой вопрос.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста! Мне просто довольно часто приходится переводить тех. документацию, и там бывают достаточно жесткие требования к дословности перевода.